# How do I bypass the Bypass startup if the person who set it is gone in Microsoft Access Plus 2010?

Tags: microsoft-access-2010

The database is set to disable the shift key when opening, but the person who set the Bypass startup is no longer employed here. We need to edit tables and a query in the background but can't get in! Is there a way to get in the background when we don't have access because the employee is gone?